# Where I can find the proof that- for every knot there is a Conway Notation?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

At the end of The Knot Book - Collin Adams there is a list of knots. He has given a Conway Notation for each of those knots, from which I have assumed that every knot has a Conway Notation. Or for every knot there is a projection which has Conway Notation. But so far I haven't found the proof.

Comment: Have you tried reading his [paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conway.pdf)?

Comment: That's because there is none. See my comment on the next Answer. --Ken Perko (lbrtpl@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

Every projection has a Conway notation. To obtain it, merge every pair of vertices (crossings) that is directly connected with two arcs into a single vertex until no such pairs left; this way you obtain a basic polyhedron. And then restore all the merged crossings in every vertex of the basic polyhedron and represent them as an algebraic tangle (every time you restore a crossing, it is effectively an algebraic tangle operation).

Comment: Conway, in his authorized biography {"Genius at Play" by Siobhan Roberts (Bloomsburym 2015), page 425], disputes this, noting that some knots are "not good enough to have a notation in my system." He could, of course, be wrong about this (like so many other things). --Ken Perko (lbrtpl@gmail.com)

Comment: I believe he means that he only listed a finite set of basic polyhedra, so an arbitrary knot may require a basic polyhedron which has no notation or description from Conway himself (i.e. any basic polyhedron starting from 12 vertices) or maybe ever (I don't know if a way to systematically list and enumerate basic polyhedra exists). In this sense -- yes, indeed, some knots are not good enough.

Comment: However it is undoubtedly possible to encode any given basic polyhedron somehow (e.g., as it is done in the LinKnot Mathematica package), so in this sense any knot is good enough.

Comment: Roberts' book is great, by the way.